# Using preg_match_all to find date format inside string, not looping correctly

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to search a string to see if it contains one or more dates in the format mm/dd/yy. The strings will always contain a sentence preceded by a date. There may be more than one date in the string, and if that occurs I need to split things into an array.

Here is an example of a string containing more than one date:

> 12/11/19 d/c 1item-customer installed.... pif cmpt12/27/19 e/c cust unhappy. cust wants new dr...149.95 quoted....ncsc cmpt12/29/20 e/c floor pif cmpt

Here is my PHP code:

```
$string = "12/11/19 d/c 1item-customer installed.... pif cmpt12/27/19 e/c cust unhappy. cust wants new dr...149.95 quoted....ncsc cmpt12/29/20 e/c floor pif cmpt";

$regex = "/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
$matchCount = count($matches[0]);
$lessmatch = $matchCount - 1;

echo "count is " . $matchCount . "\r\n";

for ($i = 0; $i <= $lessmatch; $i++) {
  
  $beginpos[$i] = strval(strpos($string,$matches[0][$i]));
  $next = $i + 1;
  // Check if last match in string
  if($i < $lessmatch) {
    $endpos = strval(strpos($string,$matches[0][$next]));
  $strbetween[$i] = substr($string,$beginpos[$i],$endpos);
  }
  if($i == $lessmatch) {
      $strbetween[$i] = substr($string,$beginpos[$i]);
  }
  
  echo $strbetween[$i] . "<br>";
}
```

I put the br tag in the echo so that I would know when the loop is moving next - so that I would know if the preg_match_all was correctly detecting the date pattern, and I echo the $matchCount variable to ensure that the script is correctly catching all occurrences. It correctly echos 3 as the count but screws up on printing things. Here is what I get:

count is 3
12/11/19 d/c 1item-customer installed.... pif cmpt
12/27/19 e/c cust unhappy. cust wants new dr...149.95 quoted....ncsc cmpt12/29/20 e/c floor pif cmpt
12/29/20 e/c floor pif cmpt

I can't figure out why it correctly shows the first and last items but on the second item it also shows the third ... then shows the third once again. I'm guessing it's how I'm looping but I can't seem to figure out how to do it correctly. Can anyone help?

Comment: Very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58809325/2943403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
$string = "12/11/19 d/c 1item-customer installed.... pif cmpt12/27/19 e/c cust unhappy. cust wants new dr...149.95 quoted....ncsc cmpt12/29/20 e/c floor pif cmpt";

print_r(preg_split("/(?!\A)(?=(?<!\d)\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(?!\d))/", $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/40kXM). Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12/11/19 d/c 1item-customer installed.... pif cmpt
    [1] => 12/27/19 e/c cust unhappy. cust wants new dr...149.95 quoted....ncsc cmpt
    [2] => 12/29/20 e/c floor pif cmpt
)
```

The pattern matches

- `(?!\A)` - not at the start of string
- `(?=(?<!\d)\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(?!\d))` - immediately to the right, there must be two  digits, `/`, two digits, `/`, two digits *not* enclosed with any other digits.

Comment: Because of NO_EMPTY, you don't even need to deny the start of the string in the pattern.  Changing the delimiter affords no escaping slashes. https://3v4l.org/X9U6E

Comment: @mickmackusa That's right, but for some reason, I prefer to play it safe all the time when using `preg_split`. Just in case someone forgets to add that flag. `(?!\A)` is not very resource consuming construct since it just checks one position, no quantified complex patterns involved.

Answer (score 3):

The actual error is that when you call `substr()`, the third parameter is the length of the text and not the end position.  This means that you are asking for more characters than you need.

There is also the possibility that if the same date occurs twice, this code will not split it correctly.  You can use `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` which will give you the position of the matched string in the string and use these values to work out the start and end (plus subtract the two when using `substr()`)...

```
$regex = "/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/";
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$matchCount = count($matches[0]);
echo "count is " . $matchCount . "\r\n";

for ($i = 0; $i < $matchCount; $i++) {
    $beginpos = $matches[0][$i][1];
    $endpos = $matches[0][$i+1][1] ?? strlen($string);
    $strbetween[$i] = substr($string, $beginpos, $endpos - $beginpos);
    echo $beginpos."->".$endpos."=".$strbetween[$i] . "<br>".PHP_EOL;
}
```